# bash script to remove special characters from filenames and then pass new name as variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to remove special characters from filenames before processing them one by one in a loop. The below script is an example where I do not known how to get `"$new_filename"`

```
for file in *.txt
do rename -n 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]//g' "$file"
process "$new_filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a shell loop, there's little reason to use `rename`here so far as I can see. So perhaps something like

```
for file in *.txt; do 
  printf -v new_filename '%s' "${file//[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]}"
  echo mv -- "$file" "$new_filename"
  process "$new_filename"
done
```

The `echo` is added as an equivalent to the `rename` command's `-n` flag.

(You may wish to add `.` to the list of included characters, especially since your selected filenames end in `.txt`).